# Oracle 11g: compare DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

Why these two select queries

```
create table tmp (d date);
insert into tmp (d) values (sysdate);

select * from tmp where d = sysdate;
select * from tmp where d = trunc(sysdate);
```

both return 0 rows?

```
select to_timestamp(d), to_timestamp(sysdate) from tmp;
```

clearly shows that both columns are equal:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(D)             | TO_TIMESTAMP(SYSDATE)
July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 | July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdaba/1)

Comment: When I ran your code, both queries *did* return 1 row - but that's because I was very fast, and I ran them at exactly midnight :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `INSERT` added a date *with time of day*, because `SYSDATE` includes a time component, accurate to one second.

Your first `SELECT` returned nothing because by the time you ran it the `SYSDATE` had a different value, a second or more older than the `SYSDATE` value at the time you did the `INSERT`.

Your second `SELECT` returned nothing because it didn't have a time of day. As mishik pointed out, if you `TRUNC` the `SYSDATE` and the `tmp.d` value, you'll get a match.

---

The `TO_TIMESTAMP` function isn't what you want to use to verify values here. It ignores the time component of a date. This query...

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_DATE('7/1/2013 12:34:56', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
FROM DUAL;
```

... will return the date 7/2/2013 *only*, without a time component.

To see what was really inserted, do something like this to see the time component of each value:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(d, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM tmp;
```

Answer (score 3):

When comparing `trunc(sysdate)` - you should `trunc` `d` too:

```
select * from tmp where trunc(d) = trunc(sysdate);
```

Simple `d=sysdate` will not work, because sysdate has changed since insert.

Comment: Sure, but why for this query `select to_timestamp(sysdate), to_char(sysdate, 'dd-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS') from dual` first column is devoid of time part and second is not?

Comment: Because of default to_timestamp behavior http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm